# Optimizing if statements in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have following code with multiple 'if' statements.

```
if($scope.level===1){

    $scope.leftWordList=true
    $scope.previewViewRight=true

    $scope.counter1=5
    $timeout($scope.startFilling, 5000)
    $scope.onTimeout = function(){

      $scope.counter1--;
      mytimeout = $timeout($scope.onTimeout,1000);

      if($scope.counter1==0){
        $timeout.cancel(mytimeout);
        $scope.counter=0
      }
    }
    var mytimeout = $timeout($scope.onTimeout,1000); 

  }

  if($scope.level===2){

    console.log("Level 2")

    $scope.leftWordList=true
    $scope.previewViewRight=true

    $scope.counter2=5
    $timeout($scope.startFilling, 5000)
    $scope.onTimeout = function(){

      $scope.counter2--;
      mytimeout = $timeout($scope.onTimeout,1000);

      if($scope.counter2==0){
        $timeout.cancel(mytimeout);
      }
    }
    var mytimeout = $timeout($scope.onTimeout,1000); 
  }
  ....
```

**$scope.level** goes on till 7, and most of the code inside 'if' is same except for few statements, so I guess there is definitely a scope for optimizing it, but I do not exactly know how.

How can I do this?

**UPDATE:**
Removed incorrect description of problem statement.

Comment: *"Essentially $scope.leftWordList=true & $scope.previewViewRight=truewill repeat in level 1 & 3 whereas, $scope.leftWordList=true & $scope.previewViewRight=true will repeat in level 2 & 4."* Um...were those really meant to be the same?

Comment: I don't know Angular, but couldn't you just do `$scope.counters = []` and then index them by number?

Comment: Side note: I strongly recommend *being consistent* with your semicolons. If you want to rely on automatic semicolon insertion, do that; if not (my recommendation), ensure you put the semicolons in where they belong.

Comment: Note: If all `if`s and not disjoint, you should rather use `if...else if...else` and not `if.. if`

Comment: @Crowder: I updated the question, I made mistake describing the problem. Actually it looks simple now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on given code, you can make it generic if you change a bit:

- You can have a `counter` object and then based on level, you can update necessary flag.
- If you have any common logic that is applicable for most, then add it before your `if`s and reset then in necessary `if`.
- If your counter has reached `0`, you should not initiate a timeout and then clear it. Just check condition before initializing it.
- Your function `onTimeout` has a similar signature in both `if`s. Try to make it a function, rather than copying it in all `if`s

#### Sample Code:

```js
$scope.counter = {
  counter1: null,
  counter2: null,
}

.
.
.

// if block
$scope.leftWordList = true;
$scope.previewViewRight = true;

$scope.counter["counter" + $scope.level] = 5
$timeout($scope.startFilling, 5000)
var mytimeout = $timeout($scope.onTimeout.bind(this, $scope.counter, $scope.level), 1000);

.
.
.

// Generic function
$scope.onTimeout = function(counter, level) {
  if (--$scope.counter["counter" + level] === 0) 
    mytimeout = $timeout($scope.onTimeout, 1000);
  else
    $scope.counter = 0    
}
```

Note: I'm assuming you are setting `$scope.counter` somewhere else. Hence I have reset it in else condition.

Comment: This solution worked, I implemented it with little modifications! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

When you find yourself with a long list of mutually-exclusive branches like that, the question becomes: Are the branches fundamentally different, or are there commonalities that can be factored?

If they're fundamentally different, either a `switch` or a function dispatch table immediately comes to mind.

But in your case, it looks a **lot** like they're just the same logic with a different counter. If so, remove your individual counter properties (`counter1`, `counter2`, etc.) and replace them with an array of counters you can index into.

Then grab the level (because if the timeout, you want a consistent value rather than dealing with it having changed before the timeout occurred) and use that throughout, see the `***` lines:

```
var level = $scope.level;                      // ***
console.log("Level " + level)                  // ***

$scope.leftWordList = true
$scope.previewViewRight = true

$scope.counters[level] = 5                     // ***
$timeout($scope.startFilling, 5000)
$scope.onTimeout = function() {

    $scope.counters[level]--;                  // ***
    mytimeout = $timeout($scope.onTimeout, 1000);

    if ($scope.counter[level] == 0) {          // ***
        $timeout.cancel(mytimeout);
    }
}
var mytimeout = $timeout($scope.onTimeout, 1000);
```

Note that this assumes all of this code is within a function and so the `mytimeout` and `level` aren't shared with other invocations of the function.

Comment: I had to use different counters because, when I used single counter variable, somehow counter was fast and it went in negative. It was strange.

Answer (score 0):

You can build an object that will help you.

The object will contain all your defenitions of the things that differ from level to level, and the rest you can place inside a "switch-case"

Something like this:

```
lvlObjects = [];
lvlObject = {};
lvlObject.level = 1;
lvlObject.leftWordList = true;
lvlObject.previewViewRight = true;
....
lvlObjects.push(lvlObject);
//same for more levels.
//then call to a function that fill the scope with current values:
function updateLevel(currentLevel) {
    $scope.level = lvlObjects[currentLevel-1].level; //if needed
    $scope.leftWordList = lvlObjects[currentLevel-1].leftWordList;
    ....
}
```